# How was information generated in the early universe?

Tags: entropy, information, unitarity

Since according to the unitarity principle of quantum mechanics the total amount of information in the universe is conserved over time, how was this information generated in the first place? And how is this question related to the fact that the (gravitational) entropy of the very early universe was very low?

Comment: Maybe there is simply no information at all and this stays constant over time. There are pseudo-information among members of the universe but I am not sure there is much else. It does not seem like the universe has a point, it rather looks like noise observed from the perspective of a dimension that would be called time.